# Using two types with one template definition

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is it possible to use two different types, one is a subtype of the other, with one template definition?

Something like:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T a, T::bar b);
```

Comment: Sorry if there is a duplicate already. I couldn't find one for hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need one more usage of `typename`

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T a, typename T::bar b);
```

because `bar` is a "dependent type" of `T`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more details.

Comment: So easy :),
Can you define it as `template <typename T1, typename T2= typename T1::bar>` ?

Comment: @PetarVelev: yes.. but it would not have identical meaning, and default would mostly be useless as `T2` would be deduced from argument.

Comment: Yes. I know that the types can be deducted from the arguments. Maybe I could've used a better example. I was trying to make it as minimal as possible